# MySQL full text fails on a particular table

Tags: php, sql, mysql, full-text-search

I've been tearing my hair as to why this fails I have the following code

```
$query = "
SELECT DISTINCT title, caption, message, url, MATCH(title, caption, message, url) AGAINST ('$searchstring' ) AS score FROM news WHERE (valid = 1) AND MATCH(title, caption, message, url) AGAINST ('$searchstring' ) UNION ALL  
SELECT DISTINCT title, caption, message, url, MATCH(title, caption, message, url) AGAINST ('$searchstring' ) AS score FROM paged WHERE (valid = 1) AND MATCH(title, caption, message, url) AGAINST ('$searchstring' )  ORDER BY score DESC";
```

I'm able to get search results from the paged table but not from the news table

Comment: please post the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE paged;` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE news;`. Also, it would help if you provided a few rows of sample data from each table including rows that you expect to be returned by your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GOT IT AT LAST, Thanks Guys.... HERE IS cause of the problem

> If a word is present in more than 50%
>   of the rows it will have a weight of
>   zero. This has advantages on large
>   datasets, but can make testing
>   difficult on small ones.
>
> A natural language search interprets
>   the search string as a phrase in
>   natural human language (a phrase in
>   free text). There are no special
>   operators. The stopword list applies. 
>   In addition, words that are present in
>   50% or more of the rows are considered
>   common and do not match. Full-text
>   searches are natural language searches
>   if the IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE
>   modifier is given or if no modifier is
>   given.

one the one hand the table had only one entry thus the 50% benchmark was overshot 
even when I duplicated the entry 5 times the 50% benchmark was still an issue and relevance 0, so I added the modifier e.g.
SELECT * FROM table WHERE MATCH(col1,col2) AGAINST('search_term' IN BOOLEAN MODE)

This is my first time posting on stackoverflow...didn't expect to get responses so fast,

Thanks

Comment: Seems like Greg answered your question? Why not mark his post as the answer?

Answer (score 2):

My guess as to what the problem is: stopwords.

From the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html):

> The stopword list applies. In addition, words that are present in 50% or more of the rows are considered common and do not match.

If `paged` didn't meet the criteria but `news` did then you'd get results for one and not the other.

Answer (score 0):

Are both tables MyISAM? Or is `news` InnoDB?

Use this query to find out if you don't know.

```
select table_name
     , engine
  from information_schema.tables
 where table_name in('news','paged');
```

Because InnoDB type tables don't support fulltext.